# Ripple Effect on the touch event UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es, uiimageview, ripple

I want to make a ripple effect on a UIImageView upon receiving the user touch. How can i do this. Opengl is a good option. But on which part of opengl should i need to concentrate. I am new to opengl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you check out cocos2d:

- http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/
- https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone

It has a built-in ripple effect.

There is sample code in their source under /tests/EffectsTest.m